# Strange File Keeps Popping Up *.mabackup

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a file that I've attempted to delete a couple of times, but seems to pop back up in the recycle bin every boot.

File is called "MABackup-2015-12-17-sched.mabackup" and is 1.85 KB in size.

I have no idea where it came from and so far have been unable to get rid of it. I installed a game on the 16th and 18th, Skyforge from my.com, though I couldn't tell you if it is related or not. I've searched online for this file extension, with no results. Malware and Virus scans have turned up nothing.

Comment: do you have mysql installed? Have you tried the utility "autoruns" from microsoft sysinternals to see if something is running a backup job on startup?

Comment: thanks for pointing me to this utility. I'll have to sort through the items and see what it is. i think i have it narrowed down to something that does backups every day, but only keeps 5 days filed. for the life of me i can't remember which program i set up for that.

Comment: as @Yorik said, it's mysql backup, if you're using mysql on your current system, then you can disable the backup option or adjust it as you need. You might even used a script to do the backup for you and forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

.mabackup Is a Ministry Assistant file backup that appears on your device from the ministry assistant app. I have it running on my android device and it backs up my report and any information I put into it to my google drive. You can change how often it backs up files in settings.

Comment: Tysm that is just what i was searching for... I have it installed on my Android